# Defining Types on Class declaration?

Tags: java, android

Im relatively new to Java, and I recently came across a syntax that I have never seen before.

```
public class loadSomeData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{ etc..}
```

The part that confuses me is the stuff between the <> brackets. I understand what each of the Types are used for in this class, but why declare them in the class declaration?

More specifically what is this: `<DataType>` called in Java so I can research it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for ["generics" in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

In brief, a collection class (or any class, really) may declare a parameterized type using that syntax so that users of the class can ensure that only objects of the same type will be stored in its collections (or otherwise operated on by it).

Before generics there was no type safety on collections such as lists:

```
List numbers = new ArrayList();
numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(123)); // OK
numbers.add("foo"); // Uh-oh!
```

But now you can ensure that only the type(s) you declare can be added:

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(123)); // OK
numbers.add("foo"); // Compile-time error!
```

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing Java's Generics feature. Here is a good tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: exactly it... one thing to note about generics, besides the syntax, that unlike .NET and C++ generics are used only in compile time and are not saved in bytecode. if u'll ever use generics + reflection u shoould keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The `<DataType>` structure is referred to as the type paramaters of the `AsyncTask` class. `AsyncTask` is a [genericized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html) Java class. This means that it can use different generic classes in its operation. See the link above.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is a *generic* type, because it can be parameterized with types just as `java.util.List`, `java.util.Set`, and numerous standard Java classes.

Read the [Java tutorial about generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) to learn more.

It's useful to declare them in the class declaration because loadSomeData (which should be named LoadSomeData, or even better: SomeDataLoader) as a specialization of AsyncTask that handles String, Integer and String, and not any other types.